# Why dividing the value of column by other column create array in pandas? (I expected to get single value)

Tags: python, pandas

I though that the operation I have was quite simple but got the result what I was not expecting. I have done following command for pandas dataframe and got array not single value. Can anyone tell me why and how to fix this?

```
df["diff"] = (df["Total Facility"] / df["Total Facility_B"] - 1) * 100
```

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

**Added**
When I apply following equation according to comment,

```
combined=(combined[["Total Facility", "Total Facility_B"]].applymap(type) == list).any()
```

I get following.

```
Total Facility  FALSE
Total Facility_B    FALSE
```

Comment: What do you get when you do: `(combined[["Total Facility", "Total Facility_B"]].applymap(type) == list).any()`

Comment: @ALollz According to your comment, I tried suggested equation and added result above. Can this be any hint?

Comment: Not sure then, I thought one of your values may have been a list, but that doesn’t seem to be it